# How do I programmatically set the interval time and run the cron in my custom module Drupal 8?

Tags: php, symfony, drupal-8

I want to use `cron` for synchronization purpose. and I find out hook for it.

```
function your_module_cron() {
   // your cron job define here!
}
```

but the problem is that. to perform the cron job I have to manually run the cron. there is also an option for autorun by least every one hour.

But I want to run the `cron` every 5 minutes.

I have already try this :

I found this code somewhere and I put it in the cron job, but nothing works, I have also used this code in my custom controller. but not working.

```
function your_module_cron() {
   $interval = $this->config->get('interval');
   if ($interval > 0) {
     $cron_next = $this->state->get('system.cron_last', 0) + $interval;
     if ((int) $event->getRequest()->server->get('REQUEST_TIME') > $cron_next) {
       $this->cron->run();
       drupal_set_message('running...'); //to confirm it is running or not
     }
   }
}
```

So I want to run the `cron` in every 5 minutes automatically. this is what I want.

Thanks!

Comment: Please have look at this 
`https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/256637`

Comment: Hi [@sibabrat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9739044/sibabrat-swain). I forgot this point to mention in my question description. which I like to mention here, I don't want to use any other module for this. as I said, I want to do this ```programmatically```. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried by doing it directly in admin/config/system/cron/jobs, I got plenty of thoses running every 15minutes but I could chose do it every 5min by going in Modify -> Run every and you pick in the select ? I'm not sure to understand whats your problem

Comment: Sorry [@StefanYYC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11964501/stefanyyc), but I can not see any option to Modify the Run Time. can you please tell me where exactly this modify option is available.

Comment: Hi sorry for late reply, you need to install the module https://www.drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron, then go in your admin/config/system/cron and you should be ready to go! Hope it will help